# Pass data from one richtextbox to another and sorting it in descending order

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a small program that registers student marks. the marks are added to a `richtextbox1` in this format

```
ID         name         sname         DOB         average
```

When textbox one is populated I want to sort this data by the highest average grade and display it in `richtextbox2`

I know that to pass data from one control to the other I can do the following

```
richtextbox2.text = rixhtextbox1.text
```

But I'm finding it hard to sort the data what approach should I use?

Comment: Can't you sort the objects which you are using to display the data in richtextbox1 and then display the sorted list to richtextbox2 instead of trying to sort the text in richtextbox1 ?

Comment: that's not really my task but I did try that as well

Comment: It is possible to sort the information richtextbox1 but it won't be a clean solution, so if you have access to the objects used to populate richtextbox1 that would be a much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you sorted the objects you are populating richtextbox1 with instead of trying to split and parse the text of richtextbox1.

Lets say you have a list with students

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
```

That list could be sorted by using something similar to this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
studentList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Average)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x=> sb.Append(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}" + Environment.NewLine,x.Id,x.Name,x.Sname,x.DOB,x.Average)));

richTextBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put that data in a better control, like a listview or datagridview.  You can make it look like a textbox by hiding the column headers, changing the row border colors (or hiding them completely), and changing the selection mode.  That way, you can use the built in sort using something like:

```
colAverage.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Descending;
```

Alternatively, if you're dead-set on using the rich text box, you're going to need to take the data from that textbox, put it in a sortable collection (array, list, dictionary), sort it, and then use that to populate the second textbox.